# How to prevent mod_rewrite recursion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to user mod_rewrite to forward user from default `index.html` to `default.php`, I've tried using:

`Redirect 301 /index.html default.php`

or

`Redirect 301 /index.html /default.php`

but it adds default.php repeatedly until it fails:

```
http://localhost/default.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.phpdefault.php
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: every example I've looked at in the last 5 minutes uses the full path before /default.php.

Comment: Any idea how I'd specify a constant that would return the `http(s)://servername/` with me having to manually specify it?

Comment: @aSystemOverload do you have `DirectoryIndex` in .htaccess or in Apache config somewhere?

Comment: No, no DirectoryIndex in apache2.conf or .htaccess